# Who is the great Epstein?

Tags: 20th-century, jews

In a [very interesting document](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1939/01/i-married-a-jew/306262/) written by an American woman in 1939, she mentions a number of times "such great Jews as Einstein, Epstein, Freud."

Well - who is this great Epstein? Unlike the other two, his name is no longer a household one in our times? Is it [Jean Epstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Epstein)?

Comment: Possibly the British - American sculptor **Jacob Epstein**  -  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Epstein

Comment: @TheHonRose I was just about to suggest Jacob too. Or perhaps, since the family was German, Paul Epstein. But short of finding the author, there's really no way to know who she meant is there?

Comment: I think you are right with Jean Epstein. Earlier portions of the article discuss film, and Epstein is mentioned earlier as well.

Answer (score 7):

If wrtten in 1939, it almost certainly refers to the scuptor Jacob Epstein.

There was a limerick popular around then:

> There’s a notable family named Stein,
>
> There’s Gert and there’s Ep and there’s Ein.
>
> Gert’s prose is all bunk,
>
> Ep’s sculpture’s just junk
>
> And nobody understands Ein.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you can source and date the limerick.